# SharePoint Online Performance with webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, performance

I have a SharePoint Online site that the performance has slowed down while crawl. Currently the home page contains a calendar WebPart that returns items that belong to [Me] and then 5 Task Lists WebParts and using `Hillbilly Tabs` to present them in their own "`Tab`" and to save space on the page. Each of these Task WebParts also have modified views that present only `[Me]` tasks.

I have also installed a `autocomplete.wsp` that points to a specific list.

Is there a faster way to query these lists and present the information related to the signed in user other than the OOTB WebParts that can improve overall site performance?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to pinpoint which of the webparts on your page is causing the slow loading? By for example just delete or add them one by one and see differences in load time?

Some general tips for improving the performance:

- Add an index as proposed by Nisarg (don't you see the Indexed Columns link in list settings?)
- Restrict number of items shown (use short lists with paging)
- Try async loading of the data (Webpart properties> Ajax Options > Async load)

Other options to load the tasks is to use Content Search Webpart or Content  Query webparts (both will result in one list of tasks). CQWB is restricted to your current site collection and can be configured to load tasks assigned to the current user. CSWB can show items from all your sitecollections but there will be some delay as it relies on the search index.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating indices on each of your list that is being queried. For instance, if your task list has a [Me] filter on "Assigned To", you could create an index on "Assigned To", which would improve the performance.

However the overall gain in performance depends upon the number of items you have in these lists that are being filtered. For instance, if you have anything above a thousand items, you should definitely check the performance with these indices.

Comment: I do not have the option to add a index for the Assigned To field. The lists each have about 3000 items.